# HTTPS subdomains redirect

Tags: nginx

I have a rule that rewrites all pages and subdomains from port 80 to 443 ssl

```
server {
listen xx.xx.xx.xx:80 default;
server_name *.xx.net;
return 301 https://xx.net;
```

}

This is nginx configuration that you see above

how can I add similar one that directs all 443 (https) **subdomains** (*.xx.net) to just xx.net?

this is for the https (443) listening part

```
server {


listen    xx.xx.xx.xx:443 ssl;
server_name   *.xx.net xx.net;

location / {
    proxy_pass  http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080;
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separate server block :

```
server {
    listen          xx.xx.xx.xx:443 ssl;
    server_name     *.xx.net;
    return 301      https://xx.net;
}
server {
    listen          xx.xx.xx.xx:443 ssl;
    server_name     xx.net;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080;
    }
}
```